# hbase import module don't succeed

Tags: hadoop, import, hdfs, hbase

I have to move some hbase tables from one hadoop cluster to another. I have extracted the tables using
`bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export \ <tablename> <outputdir> [<versions> [<starttime> [<endtime>]]]`
and I've put the return files into HDFS on my new cluster.
But when I try bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Import  , I have the strange following logs:

```
hadoop@edgenode:~$ hbase/bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Import ADCP /hbase/backup_hbase/ADCP/2022-07-04_1546/ADCP/
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hadoop/hbase/lib/client-facing-thirdparty/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.33.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Reload4jLoggerFactory]
2022-10-03 11:19:09,689 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Import: writing directly to table from Mapper.
2022-10-03 11:19:09,847 INFO  [main] client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /172.16.42.42:8032
2022-10-03 11:19:09,983 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled is deprecated. Instead, use yarn.system-metrics-publisher.enabled
2022-10-03 11:19:10,043 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-namenode:2181,datanode1:2181,datanode2:2181,datanode3:2181,datanode4:2181,datanode5:2181,datanode6:2181,datanode7:2181,datanode8:2181,datanode9:2181,datanode10:2181,datanode11:2181,datanode12:2181,datanode13:2181,datanode14:2181,datanode15:2181,datanode16:2181,datanode17:2181,datanode18:2181,datanode19:2181,datanode20:2181,datanode21:2181,datanode22:2181,datanode23:2181,datanode24:2181,datanode25:2181,datanode26:2181,edgenode:2181@0x05b970f7] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.5.7-f0fdd52973d373ffd9c86b81d99842dc2c7f660e, built on 02/10/2020 11:30 GMT
2022-10-03 11:19:10,043 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-namenode:2181,datanode1:2181,datanode2:2181,datanode3:2181,datanode4:2181,datanode5:2181,datanode6:2181,datanode7:2181,datanode8:2181,datanode9:2181,datanode10:2181,datanode11:2181,datanode12:2181,datanode13:2181,datanode14:2181,datanode15:2181,datanode16:2181,datanode17:2181,datanode18:2181,datanode19:2181,datanode20:2181,datanode21:2181,datanode22:2181,datanode23:2181,datanode24:2181,datanode25:2181,datanode26:2181,edgenode:2181@0x05b970f7] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:host.name=edgenode
2022-10-03 11:19:10,043 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-namenode:2181,datanode1:2181,datanode2:2181,datanode3:2181,datanode4:2181,datanode5:2181,datanode6:2181,datanode7:2181,datanode8:2181,datanode9:2181,datanode10:2181,datanode11:2181,datanode12:2181,datanode13:2181,datanode14:2181,datanode15:2181,datanode16:2181,datanode17:2181,datanode18:2181,datanode19:2181,datanode20:2181,datanode21:2181,datanode22:2181,datanode23:2181,datanode24:2181,datanode25:2181,datanode26:2181,edgenode:2181@0x05b970f7] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.version=1.8.0_342
2022-10-03 11:19:10,044 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-namenode:2181,datanode1:2181,datanode2:2181,datanode3:2181,datanode4:2181,datanode5:2181,datanode6:2181,datanode7:2181,datanode8:2181,datanode9:2181,datanode10:2181,datanode11:2181,datanode12:2181,datanode13:2181,datanode14:2181,datanode15:2181,datanode16:2181,datanode17:2181,datanode18:2181,datanode19:2181,datanode20:2181,datanode21:2181,datanode22:2181,datanode23:2181,datanode24:2181,datanode25:2181,datanode26:2181,edgenode:2181@0x05b970f7] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.vendor=Private Build
2022-10-03 11:19:10,044 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-namenode:2181,datanode1:2181,datanode2:2181,datanode3:2181,datanode4:2181,datanode5:2181,datanode6:2181,datanode7:2181,datanode8:2181,datanode9:2181,datanode10:2181,datanode11:2181,datanode12:2181,datanode13:2181,datanode14:2181,datanode15:2181,datanode16:2181,datanode17:2181,datanode18:2181,datanode19:2181,datanode20:2181,datanode21:2181,datanode22:2181,datanode23:2181,datanode24:2181,datanode25:2181,datanode26:2181,edgenode:2181@0x05b970f7] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
2022-10-03 11:19:10,044 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-namenode:2181,datanode1:2181,datanode2:2181,datanode3:2181,datanode4:2181,datanode5:2181,datanode6:2181,datanode7:2181,datanode8:2181,datanode9:2181,datanode10:2181,datanode11:2181,datanode12:2181,datanode13:2181,datanode14:2181,datanode15:2181,datanode16:2181,datanode17:2181,datanode18:2181,datanode19:2181,datanode20:2181,datanode21:2181,datanode22:2181,datanode23:2181,datanode24:2181,datanode25:2181,datanode26:2181,edgenode:2181@0x05b970f7] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: hadoop-yarn-client-3.3.3.jar:/home/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-3.3.3.jar:/home/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-sharedcachemanager-3.3.3.jar:/home/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-services-core-3.3.3.jar:/home/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-3.3.3.jar:/home/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-3.3.3.jar:/home/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-router-3.3.3.jar:/home/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-3.3.3.jar:/home/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-registry-3.3.3.jar:/home/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher-3.3.3.jar:/home/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice-3.3.3.jar:/home/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-timeline-pluginstorage-3.3.3.jar:/home/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-common-3.3.3.jar
2022-10-03 11:19:10,044 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-namenode:2181,datanode1:2181,datanode2:2181,datanode3:2181,datanode4:2181,datanode5:2181,datanode6:2181,datanode7:2181,datanode8:2181,datanode9:2181,datanode10:2181,datanode11:2181,datanode12:2181,datanode13:2181,datanode14:2181,datanode15:2181,datanode16:2181,datanode17:2181,datanode18:2181,datanode19:2181,datanode20:2181,datanode21:2181,datanode22:2181,datanode23:2181,datanode24:2181,datanode25:2181,datanode26:2181,edgenode:2181@0x05b970f7] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.library.path=/home/hadoop/hadoop/lib/native
2022-10-03 11:19:10,044 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-namenode:2181,datanode1:2181,datanode2:2181,datanode3:2181,datanode4:2181,datanode5:2181,datanode6:2181,datanode7:2181,datanode8:2181,datanode9:2181,datanode10:2181,datanode11:2181,datanode12:2181,datanode13:2181,datanode14:2181,datanode15:2181,datanode16:2181,datanode17:2181,datanode18:2181,datanode19:2181,datanode20:2181,datanode21:2181,datanode22:2181,datanode23:2181,datanode24:2181,datanode25:2181,datanode26:2181,edgenode:2181@0x05b970f7] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
2022-10-03 11:19:10,044 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-namenode:2181,datanode1:2181,datanode2:2181,datanode3:2181,datanode4:2181,datanode5:2181,datanode6:2181,datanode7:2181,datanode8:2181,datanode9:2181,datanode10:2181,datanode11:2181,datanode12:2181,datanode13:2181,datanode14:2181,datanode15:2181,datanode16:2181,datanode17:2181,datanode18:2181,datanode19:2181,datanode20:2181,datanode21:2181,datanode22:2181,datanode23:2181,datanode24:2181,datanode25:2181,datanode26:2181,edgenode:2181@0x05b970f7] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
2022-10-03 11:19:10,044 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-namenode:2181,datanode1:2181,datanode2:2181,datanode3:2181,datanode4:2181,datanode5:2181,datanode6:2181,datanode7:2181,datanode8:2181,datanode9:2181,datanode10:2181,datanode11:2181,datanode12:2181,datanode13:2181,datanode14:2181,datanode15:2181,datanode16:2181,datanode17:2181,datanode18:2181,datanode19:2181,datanode20:2181,datanode21:2181,datanode22:2181,datanode23:2181,datanode24:2181,datanode25:2181,datanode26:2181,edgenode:2181@0x05b970f7] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Linux
2022-10-03 11:19:10,044 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-namenode:2181,datanode1:2181,datanode2:2181,datanode3:2181,datanode4:2181,datanode5:2181,datanode6:2181,datanode7:2181,datanode8:2181,datanode9:2181,datanode10:2181,datanode11:2181,datanode12:2181,datanode13:2181,datanode14:2181,datanode15:2181,datanode16:2181,datanode17:2181,datanode18:2181,datanode19:2181,datanode20:2181,datanode21:2181,datanode22:2181,datanode23:2181,datanode24:2181,datanode25:2181,datanode26:2181,edgenode:2181@0x05b970f7] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=amd64
2022-10-03 11:19:10,044 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-namenode:2181,datanode1:2181,datanode2:2181,datanode3:2181,datanode4:2181,datanode5:2181,datanode6:2181,datanode7:2181,datanode8:2181,datanode9:2181,datanode10:2181,datanode11:2181,datanode12:2181,datanode13:2181,datanode14:2181,datanode15:2181,datanode16:2181,datanode17:2181,datanode18:2181,datanode19:2181,datanode20:2181,datanode21:2181,datanode22:2181,datanode23:2181,datanode24:2181,datanode25:2181,datanode26:2181,edgenode:2181@0x05b970f7] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=5.15.0-1018-kvm
2022-10-03 11:19:10,044 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-namenode:2181,datanode1:2181,datanode2:2181,datanode3:2181,datanode4:2181,datanode5:2181,datanode6:2181,datanode7:2181,datanode8:2181,datanode9:2181,datanode10:2181,datanode11:2181,datanode12:2181,datanode13:2181,datanode14:2181,datanode15:2181,datanode16:2181,datanode17:2181,datanode18:2181,datanode19:2181,datanode20:2181,datanode21:2181,datanode22:2181,datanode23:2181,datanode24:2181,datanode25:2181,datanode26:2181,edgenode:2181@0x05b970f7] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=hadoop
2022-10-03 11:19:10,044 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-namenode:2181,datanode1:2181,datanode2:2181,datanode3:2181,datanode4:2181,datanode5:2181,datanode6:2181,datanode7:2181,datanode8:2181,datanode9:2181,datanode10:2181,datanode11:2181,datanode12:2181,datanode13:2181,datanode14:2181,datanode15:2181,datanode16:2181,datanode17:2181,datanode18:2181,datanode19:2181,datanode20:2181,datanode21:2181,datanode22:2181,datanode23:2181,datanode24:2181,datanode25:2181,datanode26:2181,edgenode:2181@0x05b970f7] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/home/hadoop
2022-10-03 11:19:10,044 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-namenode:2181,datanode1:2181,datanode2:2181,datanode3:2181,datanode4:2181,datanode5:2181,datanode6:2181,datanode7:2181,datanode8:2181,datanode9:2181,datanode10:2181,datanode11:2181,datanode12:2181,datanode13:2181,datanode14:2181,datanode15:2181,datanode16:2181,datanode17:2181,datanode18:2181,datanode19:2181,datanode20:2181,datanode21:2181,datanode22:2181,datanode23:2181,datanode24:2181,datanode25:2181,datanode26:2181,edgenode:2181@0x05b970f7] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/home/hadoop
2022-10-03 11:19:10,044 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-namenode:2181,datanode1:2181,datanode2:2181,datanode3:2181,datanode4:2181,datanode5:2181,datanode6:2181,datanode7:2181,datanode8:2181,datanode9:2181,datanode10:2181,datanode11:2181,datanode12:2181,datanode13:2181,datanode14:2181,datanode15:2181,datanode16:2181,datanode17:2181,datanode18:2181,datanode19:2181,datanode20:2181,datanode21:2181,datanode22:2181,datanode23:2181,datanode24:2181,datanode25:2181,datanode26:2181,edgenode:2181@0x05b970f7] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.memory.free=174MB
2022-10-03 11:19:10,044 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-namenode:2181,datanode1:2181,datanode2:2181,datanode3:2181,datanode4:2181,datanode5:2181,datanode6:2181,datanode7:2181,datanode8:2181,datanode9:2181,datanode10:2181,datanode11:2181,datanode12:2181,datanode13:2181,datanode14:2181,datanode15:2181,datanode16:2181,datanode17:2181,datanode18:2181,datanode19:2181,datanode20:2181,datanode21:2181,datanode22:2181,datanode23:2181,datanode24:2181,datanode25:2181,datanode26:2181,edgenode:2181@0x05b970f7] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.memory.max=3860MB
2022-10-03 11:19:10,045 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-namenode:2181,datanode1:2181,datanode2:2181,datanode3:2181,datanode4:2181,datanode5:2181,datanode6:2181,datanode7:2181,datanode8:2181,datanode9:2181,datanode10:2181,datanode11:2181,datanode12:2181,datanode13:2181,datanode14:2181,datanode15:2181,datanode16:2181,datanode17:2181,datanode18:2181,datanode19:2181,datanode20:2181,datanode21:2181,datanode22:2181,datanode23:2181,datanode24:2181,datanode25:2181,datanode26:2181,edgenode:2181@0x05b970f7] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.memory.total=237MB
2022-10-03 11:19:10,048 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-namenode:2181,datanode1:2181,datanode2:2181,datanode3:2181,datanode4:2181,datanode5:2181,datanode6:2181,datanode7:2181,datanode8:2181,datanode9:2181,datanode10:2181,datanode11:2181,datanode12:2181,datanode13:2181,datanode14:2181,datanode15:2181,datanode16:2181,datanode17:2181,datanode18:2181,datanode19:2181,datanode20:2181,datanode21:2181,datanode22:2181,datanode23:2181,datanode24:2181,datanode25:2181,datanode26:2181,edgenode:2181@0x05b970f7] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=namenode:2181,datanode1:2181,datanode2:2181,datanode3:2181,datanode4:2181,datanode5:2181,datanode6:2181,datanode7:2181,datanode8:2181,datanode9:2181,datanode10:2181,datanode11:2181,datanode12:2181,datanode13:2181,datanode14:2181,datanode15:2181,datanode16:2181,datanode17:2181,datanode18:2181,datanode19:2181,datanode20:2181,datanode21:2181,datanode22:2181,datanode23:2181,datanode24:2181,datanode25:2181,datanode26:2181,edgenode:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ReadOnlyZKClient$$Lambda$15/257950720@1124fc36
2022-10-03 11:19:10,054 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-namenode:2181,datanode1:2181,datanode2:2181,datanode3:2181,datanode4:2181,datanode5:2181,datanode6:2181,datanode7:2181,datanode8:2181,datanode9:2181,datanode10:2181,datanode11:2181,datanode12:2181,datanode13:2181,datanode14:2181,datanode15:2181,datanode16:2181,datanode17:2181,datanode18:2181,datanode19:2181,datanode20:2181,datanode21:2181,datanode22:2181,datanode23:2181,datanode24:2181,datanode25:2181,datanode26:2181,edgenode:2181@0x05b970f7] common.X509Util: Setting -D jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true to disable client-initiated TLS renegotiation
2022-10-03 11:19:10,061 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-namenode:2181,datanode1:2181,datanode2:2181,datanode3:2181,datanode4:2181,datanode5:2181,datanode6:2181,datanode7:2181,datanode8:2181,datanode9:2181,datanode10:2181,datanode11:2181,datanode12:2181,datanode13:2181,datanode14:2181,datanode15:2181,datanode16:2181,datanode17:2181,datanode18:2181,datanode19:2181,datanode20:2181,datanode21:2181,datanode22:2181,datanode23:2181,datanode24:2181,datanode25:2181,datanode26:2181,edgenode:2181@0x05b970f7] zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocket: jute.maxbuffer value is 4194304 Bytes
2022-10-03 11:19:10,069 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-namenode:2181,datanode1:2181,datanode2:2181,datanode3:2181,datanode4:2181,datanode5:2181,datanode6:2181,datanode7:2181,datanode8:2181,datanode9:2181,datanode10:2181,datanode11:2181,datanode12:2181,datanode13:2181,datanode14:2181,datanode15:2181,datanode16:2181,datanode17:2181,datanode18:2181,datanode19:2181,datanode20:2181,datanode21:2181,datanode22:2181,datanode23:2181,datanode24:2181,datanode25:2181,datanode26:2181,edgenode:2181@0x05b970f7] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: zookeeper.request.timeout value is 0. feature enabled=
2022-10-03 11:19:10,077 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-namenode:2181,datanode1:2181,datanode2:2181,datanode3:2181,datanode4:2181,datanode5:2181,datanode6:2181,datanode7:2181,datanode8:2181,datanode9:2181,datanode10:2181,datanode11:2181,datanode12:2181,datanode13:2181,datanode14:2181,datanode15:2181,datanode16:2181,datanode17:2181,datanode18:2181,datanode19:2181,datanode20:2181,datanode21:2181,datanode22:2181,datanode23:2181,datanode24:2181,datanode25:2181,datanode26:2181,edgenode:2181@0x05b970f7-SendThread(namenode:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server namenode/172.16.42.42:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2022-10-03 11:19:10,084 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-namenode:2181,datanode1:2181,datanode2:2181,datanode3:2181,datanode4:2181,datanode5:2181,datanode6:2181,datanode7:2181,datanode8:2181,datanode9:2181,datanode10:2181,datanode11:2181,datanode12:2181,datanode13:2181,datanode14:2181,datanode15:2181,datanode16:2181,datanode17:2181,datanode18:2181,datanode19:2181,datanode20:2181,datanode21:2181,datanode22:2181,datanode23:2181,datanode24:2181,datanode25:2181,datanode26:2181,edgenode:2181@0x05b970f7-SendThread(namenode:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /172.16.42.187:48598, server: namenode/172.16.42.42:2181
2022-10-03 11:19:10,120 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-namenode:2181,datanode1:2181,datanode2:2181,datanode3:2181,datanode4:2181,datanode5:2181,datanode6:2181,datanode7:2181,datanode8:2181,datanode9:2181,datanode10:2181,datanode11:2181,datanode12:2181,datanode13:2181,datanode14:2181,datanode15:2181,datanode16:2181,datanode17:2181,datanode18:2181,datanode19:2181,datanode20:2181,datanode21:2181,datanode22:2181,datanode23:2181,datanode24:2181,datanode25:2181,datanode26:2181,edgenode:2181@0x05b970f7-SendThread(namenode:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server namenode/172.16.42.42:2181, sessionid = 0x1b000002cb790005, negotiated timeout = 40000
2022-10-03 11:19:11,001 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-namenode:2181,datanode1:2181,datanode2:2181,datanode3:2181,datanode4:2181,datanode5:2181,datanode6:2181,datanode7:2181,datanode8:2181,datanode9:2181,datanode10:2181,datanode11:2181,datanode12:2181,datanode13:2181,datanode14:2181,datanode15:2181,datanode16:2181,datanode17:2181,datanode18:2181,datanode19:2181,datanode20:2181,datanode21:2181,datanode22:2181,datanode23:2181,datanode24:2181,datanode25:2181,datanode26:2181,edgenode:2181@0x05b970f7] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x1b000002cb790005 closed
2022-10-03 11:19:11,001 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-namenode:2181,datanode1:2181,datanode2:2181,datanode3:2181,datanode4:2181,datanode5:2181,datanode6:2181,datanode7:2181,datanode8:2181,datanode9:2181,datanode10:2181,datanode11:2181,datanode12:2181,datanode13:2181,datanode14:2181,datanode15:2181,datanode16:2181,datanode17:2181,datanode18:2181,datanode19:2181,datanode20:2181,datanode21:2181,datanode22:2181,datanode23:2181,datanode24:2181,datanode25:2181,datanode26:2181,edgenode:2181@0x05b970f7-EventThread] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down for session: 0x1b000002cb790005
2022-10-03 11:19:15,366 INFO  [main] input.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 32
2022-10-03 11:19:15,660 INFO  [main] mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:32
2022-10-03 11:19:15,902 INFO  [main] mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1664271607293_0002
2022-10-03 11:19:16,225 INFO  [main] conf.Configuration: resource-types.xml not found
2022-10-03 11:19:16,225 INFO  [main] resource.ResourceUtils: Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'.
2022-10-03 11:19:16,231 INFO  [main] resource.ResourceUtils: Adding resource type - name = memory-mb, units = Mi, type = COUNTABLE
2022-10-03 11:19:16,231 INFO  [main] resource.ResourceUtils: Adding resource type - name = vcores, units = , type = COUNTABLE
2022-10-03 11:19:16,293 INFO  [main] impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1664271607293_0002
2022-10-03 11:19:16,328 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://namenode:8088/proxy/application_1664271607293_0002/
2022-10-03 11:19:16,329 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1664271607293_0002
2022-10-03 11:19:31,513 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job: Job job_1664271607293_0002 running in uber mode : false
2022-10-03 11:19:31,514 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
2022-10-03 11:19:31,534 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job: 2-10-03 11:19:31.345]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.


[2022-10-03 11:19:31.346]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.


For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://namenode:8088/cluster/app/application_1664271607293_0002 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
. Failing the application.
2022-10-03 11:19:31,552 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
```

I don't understand what the problem could be. I went to http://namenode:8088/cluster/app/application_1664271607293_0002 but i didn't found nothing interesting. I've tried the command with different tables but get the same result. The two clusters are not one the same version but I read that it wasn't a problem. Every service works well on my clusters and I can use hbase commands on the hbase shell without any problem. Also, map reduce programs works well on my new cluster. I've also tested the copyTable and snapchot methods for the data migration, which didn't work either.

Any idea of what should be the problem? Thanks! :)

update :
I found this on a datanode syslog in the hadoop web interface, may be useful?

```
2022-10-04 14:12:39,341 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil: Updating Configuration
2022-10-04 14:12:39,354 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Executing with tokens:
2022-10-04 14:12:39,493 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Kind: YARN_AM_RM_TOKEN, Service: , Ident: (appAttemptId { application_id { id: 7 cluster_timestamp: 1664271607293 } attemptId: 2 } keyId: -896624238)
2022-10-04 14:12:39,536 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: resource-types.xml not found
2022-10-04 14:12:39,536 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.ResourceUtils: Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'.
2022-10-04 14:12:39,636 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService: Service org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster failed in state INITED
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RecordFactoryPBImpl.newRecordInstance(RecordFactoryPBImpl.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.Records.newRecord(Records.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.util.MRBuilderUtils.newJobId(MRBuilderUtils.java:39)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.serviceInit(MRAppMaster.java:298)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$5.run(MRAppMaster.java:1745)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.initAndStartAppMaster(MRAppMaster.java:1742)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.main(MRAppMaster.java:1673)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RecordFactoryPBImpl.newRecordInstance(RecordFactoryPBImpl.java:70)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/v2/proto/MRProtos$JobIdProto$Builder.setAppId(Lorg/apache/hadoop/yarn/proto/YarnProtos$ApplicationIdProto;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/v2/proto/MRProtos$JobIdProto$Builder; @36: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'org/apache/hadoop/yarn/proto/YarnProtos$ApplicationIdProto' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @36
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/v2/proto/MRProtos$JobIdProto$Builder', 'org/apache/hadoop/yarn/proto/YarnProtos$ApplicationIdProto' }
    stack: { 'com/google/protobuf/SingleFieldBuilder', 'org/apache/hadoop/yarn/proto/YarnProtos$ApplicationIdProto' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ab4 0011 c700 1b2b c700 0bbb 002f 59b7
    0x0000010: 0030 bf2a 2bb5 000a 2ab6 0031 a700 0c2a
    0x0000020: b400 112b b600 3257 2a59 b400 1304 80b5
    0x0000030: 0013 2ab0                              
  Stackmap Table:
    same_frame(@19)
    same_frame(@31)
    same_frame(@40)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.proto.MRProtos$JobIdProto.newBuilder(MRProtos.java:1017)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.api.records.impl.pb.JobIdPBImpl.<init>(JobIdPBImpl.java:37)
    ... 15 more
2022-10-04 14:12:39,641 ERROR [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Error starting MRAppMaster
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RecordFactoryPBImpl.newRecordInstance(RecordFactoryPBImpl.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.Records.newRecord(Records.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.util.MRBuilderUtils.newJobId(MRBuilderUtils.java:39)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.serviceInit(MRAppMaster.java:298)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$5.run(MRAppMaster.java:1745)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.initAndStartAppMaster(MRAppMaster.java:1742)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.main(MRAppMaster.java:1673)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RecordFactoryPBImpl.newRecordInstance(RecordFactoryPBImpl.java:70)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/v2/proto/MRProtos$JobIdProto$Builder.setAppId(Lorg/apache/hadoop/yarn/proto/YarnProtos$ApplicationIdProto;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/v2/proto/MRProtos$JobIdProto$Builder; @36: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'org/apache/hadoop/yarn/proto/YarnProtos$ApplicationIdProto' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @36
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/v2/proto/MRProtos$JobIdProto$Builder', 'org/apache/hadoop/yarn/proto/YarnProtos$ApplicationIdProto' }
    stack: { 'com/google/protobuf/SingleFieldBuilder', 'org/apache/hadoop/yarn/proto/YarnProtos$ApplicationIdProto' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ab4 0011 c700 1b2b c700 0bbb 002f 59b7
    0x0000010: 0030 bf2a 2bb5 000a 2ab6 0031 a700 0c2a
    0x0000020: b400 112b b600 3257 2a59 b400 1304 80b5
    0x0000030: 0013 2ab0                              
  Stackmap Table:
    same_frame(@19)
    same_frame(@31)
    same_frame(@40)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.proto.MRProtos$JobIdProto.newBuilder(MRProtos.java:1017)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.api.records.impl.pb.JobIdPBImpl.<init>(JobIdPBImpl.java:37)
    ... 15 more
2022-10-04 14:12:39,643 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Comment: There are no error logs here, only `INFO`. Nothing has gone wrong in this log.

Comment: Yes that's what is wierd, I don't find any error log yet it doesn't work.

Comment: In my hbase and hadoop logs either